# Phonegap IOS app goes black after splash screen

Tags: ios, intel-xdk, phonegap, construct-2

I have created an android app that works perfect, however when exporting to IOS and creating with phonegap the app loads the splash screen and then the screen goes black and nothing further happens. Any insight would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I am also using intel xdk to input to phonegap.

Comment: please provide more information. this could have a lot of reasons. show us what you have tried to debug the problem. maybe parts of the code might be interesting or something else, so we dont have to guess

Comment: How can I show the full config.xml file?

Comment: don't append anything in the comments. please make use of the edit feature and improve your question

Comment: click the edit button below your question and insert it there. you can highlight it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to mark it as code